# JQuery AJAX не срабатывает success, в чем проблема?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

При клике отправляется объект на сервер, **статус==200**, но 'success' не срабатывает.
Подскажите, в чём проблема

PHP Код :

```
<?php

$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post)
{
$error = '';
$param = json_decode($_POST['param']);
$tel = $param->phone;
$money = $param->allMoney;
$suzdKol = $param->numberSuzd;
$bollKol = $param->numberBoll;
$bassKol = $param->numberBass;
$kol = $param->number;


$name_tema = "=?utf-8?b?". base64_encode($name) ."?=";

$subject ="Новая заявка с сайта CraftBurgers.com";
$subject1 = "=?utf-8?b?". base64_encode($subject) ."?=";

$message1 = "\n\nТелефон: " .$tel."\n\nОбщая сумма: " .$money." руб.\n\nКоличество Басс Бургеров: " .$bassKol."\n\nКоличество Болл Бургеров: " .$bollKol."\n\nКоличество Суздаль Бургеров: " .$suzdKol."\n\nОбщее количество: " .$kol."\n\n";
$message = "\n\nТелефон: " .$phone."\n\nИмя: " .$name."\h\h";

$header = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n";

$header .= "From: Новая заявка <example@gmail.com>\n\n";
if ($tel == null) {
    $mailMessage = mail("example@gmail.com", $subject1, iconv ('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $message), iconv ('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $header));
} else {
    $mail = mail("example@gmail.com", $subject1, iconv ('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $message1), iconv ('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $header));
}

if($mail)
{
echo 'OK';
}

}
else
{
echo 'OK';
}

?>
```

JQuery код:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(".popup-form__btn").click(function() {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://localhost/example/contact.php",
dataType: 'json',
data: "param="+JSON.stringify(burgObj),
success: function(msg) {
    $('<p>Ваш заказ принят !</p>').appendTo('.success');
},
error: function() {
    $('<p>Ошибка при передаче данных !</p>').appendTo('.success');
},
});
return false;
});
```

Comment: В консоле и нетворке что?

Comment: кривой серверный синтаксис со скобками

Comment: В консоле ничего, в нетворке статус = 200, ответ "ОК"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кривота предположительно здесь:

```
if($mail)
{
echo 'OK';
}

}
else
{
echo 'OK';
}
```

Предположу, что `else` должна быть перед последней закрывающей фигурной скобкой.

```
    if($mail) {
        echo 'OK';
    } else {
        echo 'OK';
    }
}
```

Чтобы не делать такие ошибки:

- Нужно разрабатывать в IDE, которая подсветит ошибки
- Уметь использовать отладчик для поиска ошибок

Comment: Не помогло, всё равно срабатывает error

Comment: @Дмитрий значит смотрите последние два пункта в ответе. Ставьте breakpoint'ы и делайте отладку, чтобы посмотреть, что у вас не так на сервере. А также откройте консоль браузера и посмотрите в `Network` что у вас там пишет в ответе https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL26U.png

Comment: При отправке данных статус = 200, в ответе пишет 'OK'